# One pub address to many cryptocurrency

Tags: altcoin

I've found this in the code on Github:

> This pubkey can accept any type of coin, please leave this in
>              your config to help support development.
>
> 22851477d63a085dbc2398c8430af1c09e7343f6

How do I create a similar address?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a hash160 of a public key. Generate an address, then either take the RIPEMD-160(SHA256(key)), or paste the address into this calculator: http://bitcoinvalued.com/tools.php